# Video Embed in Sidebar Widget with Links to Others in Category

Tags: widgets, sidebar, embed

I am trying to re-create the sidebar widget found here: http://www.clinicalforensicpsychology.org/

The links below the shown video are linked to the post category "videos". I have tried most every sidebar widget but I'm unable to find something that does the same thing. Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend taking a look at this article. It'll help you explain your question in a way that prompts other users to answer. http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/02/how-to-get-answers/

Answer (score 1):

I would create a Custom Post Type for Videos, and use in conjunction with some plugin like [Simple Video Embed](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-video-embedder/)

From there you can make a list of videos like so:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type= videoss','showposts=20'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
              <div class="vidoes" > 
                        <?php echo p75GetVideo($post->ID, 400); ?>
            <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
              </div>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

That will give you a list of videos with the title underneath each one. It looks like that widget uses javascript to swap out the videos.